# Python single line for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, processing, nested-loops, pyprocessing

I'm using `processing.py`

I was following this tut (Java)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7frvcAHXps

and I'm wondering if I can use the same kind of for loop in python

```
for(int y = 0; y < height; y = y + cellSize):

    for(int x = 0; x < width; x = x + cellSize):

        rect(x, 0, cellSize, cellSize)
```

I receive an error when I try to run the code:

```
processing.app.SketchException: Maybe there's an unclosed paren or quote mark somewhere before this line?
```

I guess there's probably an easy but slightly different way to do the use the same kind of nested for loops (on a single line) in python

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, `for` loop doesn't work the same in python. Please check a basic tutorial like https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: You left out the `public static void main` bit, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the equivalent in python. In `range(0, height, cellSize)`, `0` and `height` are the bounds of the range, and `cellSize` is how many out counter increments.

```
for y in range(0, height, cellSize):
    for x in range(0, width, cellSize):
        rect(x, 0, cellSize, cellSize)
```

Comment: …though you rarely, if ever, use that construction in python. You loop on containers or generators instead. Most probably here you would have a collection of cells and would simply do `for cell in grid:`

Comment: how do you have a collection of cells? without 2 nested loops?

Comment: @KippFhtagn> either by structuring your objects so you actually have a collection object, or by creating a [generator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1756156/3212865), separating *how to loop* from *what to do* while looping.

Comment: @nbryans i got how the code should be equivalent but this doesn't build a table, just a single horizontal line of rectangles

Comment: @KippFhtagn> it should be `rect(x, y, …` he translated your example into proper python but there was a mistake in the loop you put in your question.